# Finding and replacing text when there are custom elements within

Tags: linux, text-processing, sed, string, html

I have about 450 html files I need to edit. I have the directory they all are in, so that narrows things down from the perspective of searching.

What needs to be changed is a bit of known text, some unknown text, then some known text again. This would be an example:

Line 1

```
<div class="I know this"> Some random text here
```

Line 2:

```
More text</div (I know this)>
```

The above segments needs to be removed.

Below would need to be replaced. It would span multiple lines, but will be consistently the same all across.

```
<div class="oldFooter">Old Footer</div>
```

With:

```
<div class="newFooter">New Footer text</div>
```

I've found that I need to use SED, but I am not sure what exactly to put in.

Comment: Obligatory [don't parse HTML with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/7552) link

Answer (score 0):

Minimal sample:

```
cat kyo
<div class="I know this"> Some random text here
More text</div (I know this)>
<div class="oldFooter">Old Footer</div>
```

Effect:

```
sed -r '/"I know this/,/\(I know this/d;s/oldFooter/newFooter/;s/>Old Footer</>New Footer text</' kyo
<div class="newFooter">New Footer text</div>
```